Why is my 2009 Chevy Cobalt randomly not starting or starts & immediately dies?
my 2009 Chevy Cobalt is randomly not starting or sounds as if it is struggling to start, does start, and then immediately dies as if the fuel was cut off. To go back about 2 weeks, we were having an extreme heat wave/high humidity & when running the a/c, the car really struggled to have power when accelerating in 1st & 2nd gear. It has always seemed this way, but with the extreme heat /humidity, I kept having to shut the a/c off when pulling out into traffic etc to make sure I had pick up. It sucked having no a/c with the heat, so my bf installed a cold air intake, which actually made it amazing to drive even in the heat with the a/c on. It was in about a week or 2 before it didn't start for the first time & we had taken two long drives the weekend before it happened (each one about 2 hrs one way). When it first happened, I went out at 1am to leave work, & it wouldn't start. It was about 55 or 60 degrees out, the first cooler night we had. It sounded as if it wanted to start but wouldn't. Lights & radio worked without dimming. I got an Uber that night & my bf looked at it The next day, it started right up. He drove around the block 2x, parked it. Shut it off & started it again 2 or 3 x without issue, then the next time, it wouldn't start again. That night I had it towed home and when home, it started right up. My bf removed the cold air intake, It started up & again he took it for a short drive, came home, restarted and shut it off several times, again it wouldn't start or started and died. He cleaned the MAFS sensor (I think that's what it's called) and it started and continued to have no issue starting after a drive. We randomly tried it that day, no issues. That evening, we went out and stopped for gas 5 miles from home, it didn't start after we got gas. This time, it did more starting and immediately dying versus not starting at all. We pushed it to a spot, went back 4 hours later, it started right up so we drove home.  He tested the battery which said it was good, he did an alternator test and said it tested "high" but I don't know if it was voltage test or something else. The next day it started and he drove it, shut it off and restarted it and shut it off about 14 times, it started each time no problem. Something obviously isn't right though and I don't want to be stuck with a dead car at 1am. When it runs, it runs great. Doesn't seem as if it's going to stall while driving. He checked something near the engine and said it's getting fuel (some kind of port... Sorry I have no idea). Oh I should add that while having the cold air intake on there, the engine light randomly came on, with a code that indicated it was running lean, it has not thrown any codes since removing the intake. The code reader isn't indicating any issues actually. My thoughts was something was damaged from it running lean or that the computer adjusted with the cold air intake, making it wonky but hopefully with it out will adjust itself back. I know nothing about cars as much as I'd like to think I do. My bf can fix anything but troubleshooting is not his strong suit. He's not formally trained, just has learned how to fix our cars out of necessity when the problem is obvious or pointed out I know some cars don't seem to like the CAIs and I've heard not to put them in without tuning the car, which was not done with my car. Hope this all makes sense, it's a long explanation but with the weird random symptoms it warranted all the info. Other than this, the car has been very well maintained, had the oil changed every 3k miles for life and runs great normally. 152k miles. Thanks for any direction someone can point me!

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

The first thing I would check is the crankshaft position sensor. They oftentimes fail intermittently, especially in hot conditions. They are sometimes hard to diagnose. Many times they will not throw a code. One way to check is when the car doesn't start and while the engine is cranking the tachometer should move a little. If it doesn't it may be the crankshaft position sensor. Many people will just replace it because they are usually cheap and easy to replace.
Another thing to check is an intermittently failing fuel pump. This can be checked with a fuel pressure gage, which your boyfriend is familiar with. The next time it won't start, stop trying to start it and check your fuel pressure. If the pressure is lower than spec, you have a fuel supply problem. Then turn the key to the on position (not start position). Turn the key off and to the on position three times. If the pressure raises to the spec and stays there then you have a restriction (linked fuel line or dirty fuel filter). But at this time it should start. If the pressure instantly drops, replace fuel pump. If pressure is good at all times, I'd go change the crank sensor or find a shop that can diagnose this.

It may be that you have a dirty throttle body. The dirt can become sticky, and this can cause the moving parts to stick or become unstuck at different temperatures and/or after sitting for a time. The throttle body should not just be "clean enough" but "hospital clean" for best results. You will need a spray can of throttle body cleaner and a clean white rag, and possibly a clean toothbrush.
Note that if the throttle body is quite dirty now, the car may run poorly for the first few drive cycles after it is cleaned, while the engine re-learns how to control a clean throttle body. Just drive it gently if this happens, and it will get better on its own.
Cleaning the throttle body is a safe and reasonable first step toward fixing your problem, because cleaner is always better, and you can be sure that you are not throwing random parts at a problem to try to fix it. After the cleaning, if you still have the problem, at least you will know that the problem is not a dirty throttle body.
There are videos online that show how to clean the throttle body on your car. It's not hard.

It's actually a fairly new throttle body, I forgot about that. My bf had attempted to clean it about 6 months ago and somehow screwed it up. We had to replace it. Would that still be a possibility for being dirty enough to cause this issue?

@LoriVolpe It's unlikely that the throttle body would get dirty enough to cause this issue in just 6 months unless there is some other defect that is causing a buildup of gunk. At this point, it wouldn't hurt to just inspect the throttle body for cleanliness with a flashlight and inspection mirror. If soiled, it should be cleaned and perhaps start a new question to find a reason it got dirty so quickly. Hole in air filter? Wrong size air filter that fits poorly? Missing air filter?
